# How to import 2 file paths to single application by right click?

Tags: c++, qt

#### Step1: modify the right click menue

[image]

#### Step2: Qt program coding

```
// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    QSharedMemory shared("Lakers");
//    if(shared.attach()) {
//        return 0;
//    }
//    shared.create(1);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.showMainInputParas(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

```
// mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void showMainInputParas(int argc, char *argv[]);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showMainInputParas(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1: %2")
                             .arg(i)
                             .arg(QString::fromLocal8Bit(argv[i])));
    }
}
```

#### Step3: select 2 files and open

[image]

#### Step4: show the 2 file paths in single program(wrong)

[image]
I want the 2 paths showed in one single program, and I add QSharememory class in main.cpp, but I still do not know how to pass the 2 file paths into main's argc & argv

Comment: try to replace `%1` in the register with `%*`

Comment: Looks like you need to assign files for a MDI app not SDI. Here is [example](https://wiki.qt.io/Assigning_a_file_type_to_an_Application_on_Windows) with all WinAPI tricks (look at `DocumentWindow`). I did not try it but hope it helps you.

Comment: replace %1 to %* is not work; It's not about MDI or SDI, I just want the 2 selected  file paths before application open